# save XML file with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, save

I want to save XML file in "abbrxml.xml." I want to put the sentence like"'Hello world'" and then save XML. here is the code. when I try this, nothing happens. How can I save XML file with the sentence that I want to put in xml??

`type: 'button',`

```
                   id: 'btnFind',
                    align: 'left',
                    style: 'width:100%',
                    label: 'add',

                    onClick: function () {

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "get",
                            url: "abbrxml.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function (xml) {
                                $(xml).find('root').each(function () {
                                    var test = $(this).find("entry").text();
                                    var abbr = '<xml><message>Hello world</message></xml>';
                                    $("test").append(abbr);
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript can't write files on the server, as it's downloaded and run locally. You'll need to send your javascript-edited XML via AJAX to a PHP file which saves it for you, or something similar.

Comment: @ Simon M i know Javascript can't save the file, so i made the code. Isn't that AJAX??

Comment: @Albright Yes, it is AJAX, but you're just getting the XML file's contents and then appending text to the result, not actually modifying the code. So, what you now need to do is create a PHP file that appends whatever is sent to your XML file, like this: `<?php $file = fopen("abbrxml.xml", "r+"); fwrite($file, $_POST['write']); fclose($file); ?>` and get jQuery to send it an POST request like so: `$.post("yourfile.php", "write="+encodeURIComponent(abbrVar))`